# I need a ASP.NET/MVC or J2EE fully customizeable Calendar control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jakarta-ee, calendar

I have some requirements to implement a customized web based Calendar application for my company.  I am looking for a ASP.NET or J2EE based Calendar platform/framework that I can build on to meet my requirements.  I am trying to save development time, so the platform/framework that i'm looking for should provide the following:

- easy to customize the UI
- easy to addadditional views typical views (Month, Day, Week)
- Calendar API that is accessible in case the default views need additional customizations
- runs on IIS 7.5 or Tomcat 6

Here is an example of what I am looking for.  Please let me know if you know of any additional ones.

[Day Pilot](http://www.daypilot.org/)

I am willing to consider PHP & RoR based Calendars as well provided that it allows the middle tier to be coded in a different language.